# Possible values of 'a' ? $f(x)=(x^2+ 2 ax +a^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Tags: functions, real-numbers

If $$f(x)=(x^2+ 2 ax +a^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$ has its domain and range such that their union is set of real numbers,then what should be the possible values of a?
What can be the approach?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$(x^2+2ax+a^2-1)^{1/4}=\left((x+a+1)(x+a-1)\right)^{1/4}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The range of $f$ does not depend on $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is a fourth root, its range is $\mathbb{R^+\cup \{0} \}$ (since the radicand is $0$ for $x=-a\pm1$) and its domain is given by the intervals satisfying the non-negativity of the radicand. This turns out to be $$(-\infty,-a-1]\cup[-a+1,+\infty),$$ hence, for it to contain $\mathbb{R^-}$ we must have $$-a-1\ge0 \\ a\le-1$$.